# how to configure ssl certificate for both flask api and client

Tags: ssl, nginx, flask, gunicorn, uwsgi

I have made email contact form, that sends mail.
the front-end is made with HTML/CSS and JS. The JS behind `index.html` is below :

```
contactForm = document.getElementById("contact_form");
contactForm.onsubmit = (element) => {
  element.preventDefault();

  name = document.getElementById("form_name").value;
  email = document.getElementById("form_email").value;
  subject = document.getElementById("form_subject").value;
  message = document.getElementById("form_message").value;

  raw = JSON.stringify({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  subject: subject,
 message: message,
});
console.log(raw);

fetch("http://example.com:5000/contact", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: raw,
redirect: "follow",
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  if (result == "received") {
    alert("Your message has been sent");
  } else {
    alert("Sorry we couldn't send your message, please try again");
  }
})
.catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
 };
```

the flask app :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from pprint import pprint
from flask_cors import CORS
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage



app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

email_add = 'USER'
email_pass = 'PASS'


@app.route('/')
def verify():
    return "app is running"


@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST'])
def post_email():
    request_data = request.json
    pprint(request_data)

    if 'email' and 'message' and 'name' and 'subject' in request_data:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg['Subject'] = request_data['subject']
        msg['From'] = request_data['email']
        msg['To'] = email_add
        name = request_data['name']
        msg.set_content("   From " + name + ", " + "\n\n" + "  " + request_data['message'] + "\n\n" + 
"My email: " + request_data['email'])
        pprint(request_data['subject'])

        smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        smtp.login(email_add, email_pass)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
        return "received"
    else:
        return "sorry"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The app was hosted on a `linux server`, The client files were served with `Nginx` and The flask API was serving gunicorn with uwsgi. I've created a service file in systemd which is responsible for running the flask app at 0.0.0.0:5000. everything was working perfect, but when I installed SSL certificate from letsencrypt, the client files were working perfect but my flask API wouldn't work anymore. It keeps saying failed to fetch, mixed protocol used. How should I solve this problem. I've tried pyOpenSSL but it doesn't work. Is there anyway I can use the SSL in both my API and client server. thank you.
This is how I was serving my app.

```
server {
server_name www.example.com;
root /home/jimrahman/dark_second;
index index.html;


location /contact {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:5000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a SSL Certificate for your domain (e.g. example.com), with Let's Encrypt or any other SSL Cert Provider, or self-signed
2. Configure your nginx-Site (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html):

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.example.com.key;

    root /home/jimrahman/dark_second;
    index index.html;


    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:5000;
    }
}
```

You might have to configure some other things to have solid "good" ssl.

3. Use `www.example.com/api` or simply `/api` if running on the same server as base path for your api, so if you use fetch to call it:

```js
fetch("/api/contact", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow",
})
```

4. If you are running both services on different servers you might have to think about cors. But be careful how you configure CORS. It can be dangerous to just open your api to all Origins. https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, but when I fetch("/contact") I am getting a bad gateway error. any thoughts on how should I handle it.

Comment: If you use your config so far, it would be a call to "/contact/contact", with the config example I provided you need to use "/api/contact". Its pretty hard to tell whats the problem without knowing your exact config.